# Select maximum number of rows meeting this condition

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I encountered this problem in a coding contest, which boils down to following problem:

What's the maximum number of rows that can be selected from a binary matrix such that no two rows have column AND of non-zero. (All pairs for rows should have column wise AND zero).

Constraints: rows<=50  , columns<=20

Eg.

00101101

10110001

10000010

The answer is 2, (First and Third rows).

I could figure that there was some exponential algorithm in number of columns (because of constraints). I just couldn't reach to the solution. All my other tries were too complicated with creating a graph and finding Independent set and those also were exponential in number of rows. Can someone help me with the solution for this?

I tried to check out other contestants code after the contest, they seem to be solving it with DP. I am not asking for full solution. I'd appreciate a little detailed hints.

EDIT:

If the description is not clear, the selected rows should not have common one in same column (Sorry if it's still not clear). Like in the given example, first and second row cannot be selected because they have one in 3rd and 8th column. Similarly 2nd and 3rd row cannot be selected because they have common one in 1st column. There is NO COMMON ONE in 1st and 3rd rows.

Comment: ... "such that no two rows have column AND of non-zero. (All pairs for rows should have column wise AND zero). " What does that mean? You might have left out a few words because I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I have tried to be more clear about it in the edit. Please let me know if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the NP-hard set packing problem. The intended O(m 2^n)-time solution (where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns, less than the word size) prepares a table indexed by 0..m times 0..2^n-1, where cell (i, j) is the maximum number of rows with indexes from 0..i whose pairwise intersections/ANDs are empty/zero and whose union/OR is j.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Could you please detail your solution a little more. I'd really be glad.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing gives the equivalent problem of determining whether there are k subsets, out of a collection of given subsets of a universal set of N elements, such that none of the k chosen subsets intersect. The maximization problem is obvious and can be solved in polynomial time if the decision problem can be solved in polynomial time: The maximization problem asks for the maximum k such that k subsets can be found such that none of the k subsets intersect.

Unfortunately these problems are NP-hard (specifically, the decision problem for specific k is NP-complete), so unless P = NP, there is no universal fast solution for your problem. Maybe given the low number of rows and columns in your problem, a "fast enough" solution can be devised. However based on my initial reading of the classical set packing problem, it's not clear how such a solution would work.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in the description that I wanted an exponential algorithm in number of columns. Please re-read the description.

Comment: @Naman, I understand, I tried to find a solution in the literature that was either mildly exponential in number of columns or rows, but I didn't find one. I was merely trying to point out, almost at the same time as David Eisenstat, that there is almost certainly no polynomial time algorithm for your problem, because it's NP-hard. You didn't mention that in your post so I wanted to let you know. "Dynamic programming" can be polynomial, pseudo-polynomial, or exponential time, depending on the problem and what is variable. I was trying to guide your search for a dynamic programming algorithm.